# node-soap returns error "No such operation"

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I'm trying to setup soap client using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) package. I have to connect to API of ADVCash payment system.

so, I create the Client like this:

```
try
  client = Soap.createClient("https://wallet.advcash.com/wsm/merchantWebService?wsdl")      
catch error
  console.log error
```

and then call

```
client.getBalances(params)
```

as result I have error

```
error: 'soap-method',
reason: 'Soap method call failed',
details: { [Error: soap:Server: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /wsm/merchantWebService)] stack: [Getter] },
message: 'Soap method call failed [soap-method]',
```

I have asked payment system's support about this error and they told me that probably I use HTTP GET method instead of HTTP POST.
I didn't found in node-soap package's docs any instructions of how can I check/set what http method package is using. 
Can anybody help me resolve this issue?
How can I set http method POST for the request?

Comment: Make sure you to use the correct operation in the request.

Comment: thanks. Seems it is correct. Method getBalances exists.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue ???